# Pyspark Collect Action on large dataframe does not return the list items

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a pyspark application and have a large dataset having 100 million records. I am collecting that into a list for some operations later.

However, it will not return the list and ends abruptly without an error. I tried printing the length of the list, even that fails.

The instance has 64Gb RAM and 500Gb of storage with 16CPU's

The code is simple enough:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shufflepartitions",32)
df=spark.read.format(file_type).option("header", True).load(filename)
list_of_items=df.collet()
print(len(l1)) #doesn't print anything
```

I am using below command to run spark job

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --driver-memory 5g --executor-memory 16g load.py
```

I tried restricting that to a smaller dataset up to 1 million records and it worked fine and printed the number of items in list. Can spark not handle list of data for such large datasets?

Comment: `collect` is the action function to collect all data into a single driver node which you specify the memory size as 5g and default size of `driver.maxResultSize` = 1g. so I bet you are exceeding the memory limit. `collect` with 100mil is not a good idea.  What do you want to do with the list? maybe you can do that in spark operations.  Typically, when you have to take data with `collect`, you want to aggregate or filter to make dataframe smaller before the `collect`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put the driver.maxresultsize=50g is also there. I am basically comparing two datasets. What I want to do is to hash all row values into another column and make a single string out of new column by concatenating all list values with either a comma or a space. Both these lists will then be used for quick comparison of the dataframes instead of going for full comparison of the dataframes.

Comment: If you use the list to compare against the another dataframe, I am pretty sure there is a way to do this in Spark dataframe operations in a distributed way. That is way more efficient than `collect` / `compare`.  Would you like to add your small sample input and expected output and a description of how you want to compare?